# Codeigniter/ PHP - using global variables in a self made library

Tags: codeigniter, variables, global, libraries

I've made my own library in codeigniter and I have multiple functions with in the library.

Now these functions refer to a group of global variables.

Now what I've done inside the class is declare variables by saying `protected $myvar;` but when I refer to these variables within my functions,

I get `errors saying $myvar is undefined`... Please help...

Comment: post some code? Where are you defining those vars at?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In OOP context, you have to use `$this->myvar`, not just `$myvar`.